# Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-archetype-plugin:2.4:generate

Tags: java, apache, maven, struts2

I'm using instructions mentioned at [apache website](https://struts.apache.org/docs/struts-2-maven-archetypes.html) to create Struts2 convention based app with the following Maven command:

```
mvn archetype:generate -DgroupId=com.example.apps -DartifactId=phonedirectory -Dversion=1.0 -DinteractiveMode=false -DarchetypeGroupId=org.apache.struts -DarchetypeArtifactId=struts2.archetype-convention -DarchetypeVersion=2.3.24.1 -DremoteRepositories=http://struts.apache.org -e
```

But I get the following error:

```
[INFO] Error stacktraces are turned on.
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Maven Stub Project (No POM) 1
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] >>> maven-archetype-plugin:2.4:generate (default-cli) > generate-sources @ standalone-pom >>>
[INFO] 
[INFO] <<< maven-archetype-plugin:2.4:generate (default-cli) < generate-sources @ standalone-pom <<<
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-archetype-plugin:2.4:generate (default-cli) @ standalone-pom ---
[INFO] Generating project in Batch mode
[WARNING] Archetype not found in any catalog. Falling back to central repository (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2).
[WARNING] Use -DarchetypeRepository=<your repository> if archetype's repository is elsewhere.
Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/struts/struts2.archetype-convention/2.3.24.1/struts2.archetype-convention-2.3.24.1.jar

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 23.619 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2015-11-09T11:49:41+05:30
[INFO] Final Memory: 15M/114M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-archetype-plugin:2.4:generate (default-cli) on project standalone-pom: The desired archetype does not exist (org.apache.struts:struts2.archetype-convention:2.3.24.1) -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-archetype-plugin:2.4:generate (default-cli) on project standalone-pom: The desired archetype does not exist (org.apache.struts:struts2.archetype-convention:2.3.24.1)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:212)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:307)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:193)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:106)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:862)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:286)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:197)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoFailureException: The desired archetype does not exist (org.apache.struts:struts2.archetype-convention:2.3.24.1)
    at org.apache.maven.archetype.mojos.CreateProjectFromArchetypeMojo.execute(CreateProjectFromArchetypeMojo.java:205)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)
    ... 20 more
Caused by: org.apache.maven.archetype.exception.UnknownArchetype: The desired archetype does not exist (org.apache.struts:struts2.archetype-convention:2.3.24.1)
    at org.apache.maven.archetype.ui.generation.DefaultArchetypeGenerationConfigurator.configureArchetype(DefaultArchetypeGenerationConfigurator.java:119)
    at org.apache.maven.archetype.mojos.CreateProjectFromArchetypeMojo.execute(CreateProjectFromArchetypeMojo.java:189)
    ... 22 more
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
```

The corporate internet connectivity and firewall filtering rules seems to be ok.
I've no idea why the struts2-archetype-convention isn't available at the remote repo http://struts.apache.org.

If anybody faced the similiar issue then please share the solution.

Comment: Always pay attention to this kind of things... the archetype is correct on the apache website, the error has been introduced by you ;) I've lost one hour once to get that in struts.xml I've used extends="struts_default" instead of extends="struts-default".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maven is searching for the following:

```
struts2.archetype-convention
```

whereas, it should be searching for

```
struts2-archetype-convention
```

The final link should be:

```
https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/struts/struts2-archetype-convention/2.3.24.1/struts2-archetype-convention-2.3.24.1.jar
```

so, change

```
-DarchetypeArtifactId=struts2.archetype-convention
```

to

```
-DarchetypeArtifactId=struts2-archetype-convention
```